# Multiprocessing in python [broken pool process]

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I am new to the multiprocessing and exploring how to use them. As I refer to [python documentation example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor), I just tried one of my functions but my jupyter notebook gave me an error. What could be the reason?

```
import concurrent.futures

def dummy(x):
    return x**(1/200)

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executer:
        x =[1,2,3,4,5,6]
        future = executer.map(dummy,x)
        for result in future:
            print(result)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and the error is : How will I fix this? I have the latest version of Python.

---

> BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated
> abruptly while the future was running or pending.

Comment: check my edit that I accurately represented your code. Otherwise it runs just fine for me. I cannot reproduce this error with your code. Typically this error occurs when you provide an `initializer` function to the pool constructor that raises an error when it is called. It can also happen however if a worker process fails to start at all (some servers impose limits on number of processes), or if a worker process is killed from an external source (antivirus maybe.. idk).

Comment: Same here. Works without error.

Answer (score 0):

looks like as I was using Jupyter notebook, it was the problem. I just read the line from the documentation, " The **main** module must be importable by worker subprocesses. This means that ProcessPoolExecutor will not work in the interactive interpreter".